# The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'import'

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am using Spring security for my Maven web application and I have created the spring-security.xml file for handling authentication. In that I am trying to import one bean from another file, Beans.xml using import. When I did this the following error occured.

The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'import'

Beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id = "dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
     <property name = "driverClassName" value = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name = "url" value = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Employee_Management"/>
      <property name = "username" value = "root"/>
      <property name = "password" value = "root"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id = "transactionManager" 
      class = "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
      <property name = "dataSource"  ref = "dataSource" />
   </bean>

   <bean id = "employeeJDBCTemplate" class = "com.utility.EmployeeJDBCTemplate">
     <property name = "dataSource"  ref = "dataSource" />
     <property name = "transactionManager" ref = "transactionManager"/>
   </bean>

   <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <import resource="Beans.xml"/>

    <http entry-point-ref="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" auto-config="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
        <form-login login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login?logout"/>
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="employeeAuthenticationProvider" class="com.authentication.EmployeeAuthenticationProvider">
      <beans:property name="employeeJDBCTemplate" ref="employeeJDBCTemplate" />
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="employeeAuthenticationProvider"/>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="/login"/>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

Here I have used "employeeJDBCTemplate" bean from the imported bean file. But the import tag produces error. The spring-security.xml and Beans.xml are available in the same folder. Also I tried by moving the Beans.xml file to resources folder. Even then I am getting the same error. Spring version used is 4.3.4 and spring security version is 4.2.0. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `spring-security.xml` the default namespace is `http://www.springframework.org/schema/security` (the 'security' namespace) and not `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans` (the 'beans' namespace). `import` element is defined in 'beans' namespace, so to access it, you have to qualify `<import>` with `beans:` prefix.

Try

```
<beans:import resource="Beans.xml"/>
```

instead of

```
<import resource="Beans.xml"/>
```